# Getting connection failed in Hyperledger Fabric sample

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Hello i am new to Hyperledger Fabric.

I have just started to work with it, i was doing the very first sample from 
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html

I followed prerequisite installation from 
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html

my OS is **ubuntu 16.04 and i am behind proxy**

When i Run `node query.js` i get below error

```
Create a client and set the wallet location
Set wallet path, and associate user PeerAdmin with application
Check user is enrolled, and set a query URL in the network
Make query
Assigning transaction_id: a85d2111f5d6e5eef064f87de42be677e69849724b1242dca0503be84d397f5d
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Connect Failed
at /home/nokia/hyperledger/firstApp/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:434:17
returned from query
Query result count = 1
error from query = { Error: Connect Failed
at /home/nokia/hyperledger/firstApp/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:434:17 code: 14, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }
Response is Error: Connect Failed
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of "docker ps" and "docker ps -a"

Comment: `docker ps -a`
https://pastebin.com/euCLkj8e

Comment: `docker ps`

https://pastebin.com/c3Wmi124

Comment: Is your client on the same machine as the containers?

Comment: Can you try running "curl -X HEAD http://localhost:7051" ?

Comment: `curl -X HEAD localhost:7051`
Warning: Setting custom HTTP method to HEAD with -X/--request may not work the
Warning: way you want. Consider using -I/--head instead.

`curl localhost:7051 `
no o/p

`curl --head localhost:7051`
no o/p

Comment: Yes client is on the same machine as host.

Comment: if i curl on the couchdb i can see the result
`curl  localhost:5984`
{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"2.0.0","vendor":{"name":"The Apache Software Foundation"}}

Comment: oops - I meant curl -X HEAD http://localhost:7051

Comment: yups tried that `curl -X HEAD localhost:7051` is only giving

Warning: Setting custom HTTP method to HEAD with -X/--request may not work the
Warning: way you want. Consider using -I/--head instead.

Comment: i get below o/p if i use Sudo
`sudo curl -X HEAD localhost:7051
Warning: Setting custom HTTP method to HEAD with -X/--request may not work the
Warning: way you want. Consider using -I/--head instead.
curl: (18) transfer closed with 2707 bytes remaining to read`

Comment: Can this is a user permission  issue?

Answer (score 3):

When the peer goes down or not responsive we see this error. I could recreate the same issue by stopping the peer. once it is started again.

```
$ docker stop peer0.org1.example.com
peer0.org1.example.com

$ node query.js
Create a client and set the wallet location
Set wallet path, and associate user  PeerAdmin  with application
Check user is enrolled, and set a query URL in the network
Make query
Assigning transaction_id:  c450608388799e3ca76e20b96010283202832c31ba9ae62c1ae4648c6353334b
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Connect Failed
    at /home/ibmadmin/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:434:17
returned from query
Query result count =  1
error from query =  { Error: Connect Failed
    at /home/ibmadmin/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:434:17 code: 14, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }
Response is  Error: Connect Failed
```

**Could see the response for the query, once the peer is started**

```
$docker start peer0.org1.example.com
peer0.org1.example.com

    $node query.js
    Create a client and set the wallet location
    Set wallet path, and associate user  PeerAdmin  with application
    Check user is enrolled, and set a query URL in the network
    Make query
    Assigning transaction_id:  21a6cc3cd27e098da355da00ba3aa8819e84bc4c2e81768dba2a88a8125b380c
    returned from query
    Query result count =  1
    Response is  [{"Key":"CAR0", "Record":{"colour":"blue","make":"Toyota","model":"Prius","owner":"Tomoko"}},{"Key":"CAR1", "Record":{"colour":"red","make":"Ford","model":"Mustang","owner":"Brad"}},{"Key":"CAR2", "Record":{"colour":"green","make":"Hyundai","model":"Tucson","owner":"Jin Soo"}},{"Key":"CAR3", "Record":{"colour":"yellow","make":"Volkswagen","model":"Passat","owner":"Max"}},{"Key":"CAR4", "Record":{"colour":"black","make":"Tesla","model":"S","owner":"Adriana"}},{"Key":"CAR5", "Record":{"colour":"purple","make":"Peugeot","model":"205","owner":"Michel"}},{"Key":"CAR6", "Record":{"colour":"white","make":"Chery","model":"S22L","owner":"Aarav"}},{"Key":"CAR7", "Record":{"colour":"violet","make":"Fiat","model":"Punto","owner":"Pari"}},
{"Key":"CAR8", "Record":{"colour":"indigo","make":"Tata","model":"Nano","owner":"Valeria"}},{"Key":"CAR9", "Record":{"colour":"brown","make":"Holden","model":"Barina","owner":"Shotaro"}}]
```

However, in your case peer seems to be running.
To understand more, can you share the peer logs please.

**docker logs -f peer0.org1.example.com**

Comment: The above log had couchdb connection error
I resolved it, by modifying my /etc/hosts file 
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       Openwhisk-Node2-172
172.18.0.3      couchdb
172.18.0.5      peer0.org1.example.com
172.18.0.2      orderer.example.com
172.18.0.4      ca.example.com

but **still  same issue**. The new logs are attached below

https://pastebin.com/1CH6ikqe

Comment: Can this be any certificate or proxy issue?... Need pointers as to how to debug.  Thanks

Comment: Is the client on the same machine as the Docker containers?

Comment: Yes client is on the same machine

Comment: Latest Logs of docker logs -f peer0.org1.example.com

https://pastebin.com/rt8bnTKR